# Data Loader functionality issue

Tags: data-loader

I'm consistently having issues with Data Loader functionality.

When I try to run Data Loader 50.0 with Zulu 11 (for MacOS 10.13 or later)when I attempt to browse for CSV files, it always greys out and I can't get any further and I am forced to quit the application.

[image]

My Macbook is actually MacOS 11.0 Big Sur - So I wondered if I should use a different Zulu version - 11.0 or later.

However, when I try to run on this version, I get the following error:

[image]

Hoping someone can help thanks!

Comment: see https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader/issues/217